# How to link a nodelet to external libraries?

Tags: ros, linking, nodelet

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to use a nodelet with an external library. But when running the nodelet, it obviously complaints that it can't find some symbol which is in this external library.

I can link the regular node the library without problems. However, when I use the nodelet version, it complains. I'm certain that I'm not linking the nodelet to the library. I don't know how to.

If you know how to link a nodelet to an external library, please share your know-how-to.

The proposed **SOLUTION** in CMakeLists.txt relevant piece looks like the following:

```
set(MVIMPACT_LIBRARIES   mvDeviceManager)

# Nodelet:  
rosbuild_add_library(mv_bluefox_driver_nodelet src/nodelets.cpp src/camera.cpp) 
# Linking the nodelet to the mvDeviceManager library
target_link_libraries(mv_bluefox_driver_nodelet ${MVIMPACT_LIBRARIES})  

# Regular Node:
rosbuild_add_executable(camera_node src/camera_node.cpp src/camera.cpp)
target_link_libraries(camera_node ${MVIMPACT_LIBRARIES})
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11299/how-to-link-a-nodelet-to-external-libraries?/) by [ubuntuslave](https://answers.ros.org/users/631/ubuntuslave/) on ROS Answers with karma: 347 on 2011-09-23

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ubuntuslave](https://answers.ros.org/users/631/ubuntuslave/) on 2011-09-25**:
Runtime problem with the error pointing at some function (DMR_Init) from the external library as:  symbol lookup error: /DIR_TO_MY_PACKAGE/mv_bluefox_driver/lib/libmv_bluefox_driver_nodelet.so: undefined symbol: DMR_Init

**Comment by [Daniel Stonier](https://answers.ros.org/users/51/daniel-stonier/) on 2011-09-24**:
Compile time problem or runtime problem?

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2011-09-24**:
Please show snippets of your CMakeLists.txt for both the node and the nodelet versions. That should help diagnose your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
target_link_libraries(mv_bluefox_driver_nodelet ${MVIMPACT_LIBRARIES})
```

The nodelet is basically a library with some programming voodoo that tells the nodelet manager which class to instantiate.

The `target_link_libraries` command links libraries against the binary that you name in its first argument. You already did it for the `camera_node` executable, and it works the same way for the `mv_bluefox_driver_nodelet` library.

---

Originally posted by [roehling](https://answers.ros.org/users/798/roehling/) with karma: 1951 on 2011-09-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ubuntuslave](https://answers.ros.org/users/631/ubuntuslave/) on 2011-09-26**:
Thanks, this was the solution.

**Comment by [Hendrik Wiese](https://answers.ros.org/users/295/hendrik-wiese/) on 2018-01-15**:
Does this work with statically linked 3rd party libraries? Like, libs of which I only have a `.a` and a `.hpp`? If not, what else can I do to achieve that linkage?

**Comment by [roehling](https://answers.ros.org/users/798/roehling/) on 2018-05-04**:
It will probably work for x86_64, but not for i386, because static 32 bit libraries are usually not compiled with -fPIC for position independent code.